# Erro em chamada de uma aplicação Python (+OpenCv) no Visual Studio 17 (C#)

Tags: c#, python, opencv, visual-studio-2017, pycharm

Estou tentando fazer um "painel de controle" que cada botão vai chamar uma aplicação Python(+OpenCV) mas quando eu executo ela pela IDE PyCharm, ou direto da pasta, ele roda perfeitamente, mas quando faço a chamada pelo Visual 17, ele aparece o seguinte erro 
[image: Error 01][ https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1SpD.jpg ]

chamada do visual (c#)

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/Barce/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/exemplo3.py"); }`

Comment: Se você rodar direto no terminal o funcionamento é normal?

Comment: @MarcosdaCruzSibilioJr. sim, ele roda normalmente, só quando chamo ele pelo visual que da esse erro